# How to gracefully get pasted value in paste event?

Tags: javascript, paste

I created UI where pasting text into textarea sends request to my API immediately. The problem is that `paste` event doesn't seem to be aware of the pasted value, unless I'm missing something. If I use `event.target.value` directly, it returns the value from *before* the pasting occured.

I used `setTimeout()` with `0ms` and it works (but I'm not happy):

```js
document.getElementById('my-textarea').addEventListener('paste', event => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const contents = event.target.value;

        // fetch() using `contents`
    }, 0);
});
```

Is there some cleaner way?

Comment: Did you try `preventDefault` and reading from `event.clipboardData` instead?

Comment: `event.clipboardData` has it, I was hoping to get something more straightforward to use other than this clunky Clipboard API with callbacks.

Comment: @morganney and why would I `preventDefault()` ?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to, but seems you need to read from `clipboardData`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event)

> A handler for this event can access the clipboard contents by calling getData() on the event's clipboardData property.

> To override the default behavior (for example to insert some different data or a transformation of the clipboard contents) an event handler must cancel the default action using event.preventDefault(), and then insert its desired data manually.

So you can try this:

```js
document.getElementById('my-textarea').addEventListener('paste', event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const contents = event.clipboardData.getData('text')
});
```

Comment: Do you know if both `text` and `text/plain` are safe to use?